# How Force browser to reload cached static file with versioning?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache

After deploying a new version of a website the browser loads everything from its cache from the old webpage until a hard, force refresh is done.

In `ASP.NET MVC` if the file becomes in Bundle, it handled by Optimization framework. a version added to your file link, and if a change occurs in your bundle's file a new token generate. follow below code :

for example, `js` file name is: `datatables`

when you put it in a bundle with the same name, you will see the

```
datatables?v=anY9_bo7KitrGnXQr8ITP3ylmhQe9NDzSjgLpLQWQFE1
```

as a file name.
change `datatables` and watch again the name of the file in the browser, surely it will change:

```
datatables?v=r8yhQBxKyDgrOGyqr1ndtdG92Ije09nqTY7yogrOSTk1
```

But there's two questions:

- What we can do if our file wasn't in Bundle?
- Is a way to force the browser to refresh cache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we have one solution with some different way for implementation. we use above solution for it.

```
datatables?v=1
```

we can handle the version of the file, it's mean that every time that we change our file, change the version of it too. but it's not a suitable way.

another way used Guide, it wasn't suitable too, because each time it fetches the file and doesn't use from the browser cache.

```
datatables?v=Guid.NewGuid()
```

The last way that is the best Way is :

when file change occur , change version too. check follow code :

```
<script src="~/scripts/main.js?v=@File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath("/scripts/main.js")).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")"></script>
```

by this way, when you change the file, `LastWriteTime` change too, so the version of the file will change and in the next when you open the browser, it detects a new file and fetch it.

Comment: Better to put the logic inside a helper method, because of all the benefits that functions have, including: Make your code testable, avoid repeating the file path twice, also changing the logic without changing this aspx/cshtml file.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you cannot use bundling for some reason, the solution suggested by the original poster is good enough, however it's better to put the logic inside a [helper method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

It makes the code testable, it helps to change the logic without changing `.cshtml` , and also helps to not repeat the filename twice. Then you can have have a much cleaner code:

```
<script src="@Url.ContentWithVersion("~/scripts/main.js")"></script>
```

To do so, you can add `ContentWithVersion` extension method to the existing [`UrlHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string ContentWithVersion(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string path)
    {
        if (urlHelper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(urlHelper));
        var result = urlHelper.Content(path);
        var file = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
        if (File.Exists(file))
            result += $"?v={File.GetLastWriteTime(file).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}";
        return result;
    }
}
```